# What is the fastest way to do LIKE queries on jsonb/json columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

we have a PostgreSQL 14 database with two columns: one jsonb and one json column. The first one is for fast jsonpath querying and has a GIN index. The second one is just to keep the original JSON.
I want to do text searches in the json using text snippets. However, using the LIKE operator like this is rather slow (as expected):

```
and x."jsonb" ::text LIKE '%"test" : 10%'
```

when I want to search for this ANYWHERE in the JSON:

```
"test" : 10
```

It seems that with jsonpath it is not that easy to achieve full text searches without regexes which are also slow. Not that I really want a full text search and not some comparison with a specific key in the JSON.

What would be the fastest way to do such a query?
Of course I can still limit the number of searched entries with a date but it would be nice to have something much faster.

Comment: There is no good way to do that. Think of a better data model that using JSON columns and arbitrary substring searches.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the correct index.

```
create index on x using gin (("jsonb"::text) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: Is this really much faster than already having an index on the column "jsonb" itself? If yes, I will do this. And does this have any disadvantages like slower database operations in general?